# Time synchronization over the network in C++

Tags: c++, synchronization, c++-chrono

I'm modding a game (Portal 2). I want to add a countdown function to start a race.

Using SFML library, I'm sending `time_since_epoch` of a `system_clock` to the local computer and a distant one through sockets. Once it's received, I compare the time_since_epoch received and the one given by the `now()` function.

So that I'm able to get the time that the socket took to send the message, which should be the current ping (~4ms).

It works fine on the same computer executing the server. However, it gives me a very big number on a distant one.
Here's my code:

**Server side:**

```cpp
void NetworkManager::StartCountdown()
{
    sf::Uint64 epoch = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();

    sf::Packet countdown_packet;
    countdown_packet << HEADER::COUNTDOWN << epoch;
    for (auto& socket : this->socket_pool) {
        socket->send(countdown_packet);
    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```cpp
void NetworkGhostPlayer::Countdown(sf::Uint64 epoch)
{
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4));
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now).time_since_epoch().count() - epoch;
    console->Print("%lld\n", diff);
}
```

`Countdown()` is called after receiving the packet and informations in it. `console->Print()` is a Portal 2 function to print in the game console.
Portal 2 is executing the client side.

On the local computer, the console prints `0`. But on the distant one, it gives numbers between `300` and `1000`.
I though it was related to the ping, which is of ~4ms, but I tested on the local computer with the `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4));` line, and the output was `4` as expected.

I don't understand what is the problem. If I execute the server on another computer, then the new local game instance gives 0 and the new distant one gives a big number.

Both computers are on Windows. Here's the complete code of the plugin : https://github.com/Blenderiste09/SourceAutoRecord/blob/Network-ghosts/GhostServer/NetworkManager.cpp

and

https://github.com/Blenderiste09/SourceAutoRecord/blob/Network-ghosts/src/Features/Demo/NetworkGhostPlayer.cpp

Thank you very much for your help !

Blenderiste09

Comment: You probably need to work out the clock drift between the 2 computers and then adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Have you taken into account that clocks on two different machines are not synchronized? The common difference might constitute even up to a few seconds. In order to measure PING you must measure RTT (Round Trip Time) which is the forth and back travel duration measured on the same side.

Comment: @RichardCritten how can I do that ? I searched on Google and I didn't find anything :/

Comment: @bloody I have another function to measure the ping and it gives me ~4ms on average because the distant computer is on the same local network.

Comment: You can measure the ping by the time half a round trip takes.  So: send your local time to the remote computer, the remote computer sends your time back to you together with it's local time.  Now you have all the information to workout the clock drift between the 2 computes.  Note your should repeat this process as computer clocks can drift.  A better solution is not to trust the remote computers at all and instead use a master computer broadcasting a time signal which all clients use as their race timer.

Comment: Ever heard of [NTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)?